# Make cardview equal in Tablelayout

Tags: android

I wrote `cardview` style in xml. I use `Tablelayout` and when I put the cardview style- 3 times, the center cardview its not equal to other cardview.I make them equal to each other. What I need to change in the code or add to make the cardview equal?

This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/simpleTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"> <!-- stretch the second column of the layout-->

    <!-- first row of the table layout-->


<TableRow>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/cardview_id1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        cardview:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/finger"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_fingerprint"
                android:onClick="Move_fingerprint"
                android:src="@drawable/fingerprint_64" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/book_title_id1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="Move_fingerprint"
                android:text="Book Title"
                android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/cardview_id2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        cardview:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/finger2"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_fingerprint"
                android:onClick="Move_fingerprint"
                android:src="@drawable/fingerprint_64" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/book_title_id2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="Move_fingerprint"
                android:text="Book Title"
                android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/cardview_id3"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        cardview:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/finger3"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_fingerprint"
                android:onClick="Move_fingerprint"
                android:src="@drawable/fingerprint_64" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/book_title_id3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="Move_fingerprint"
                android:text="Book Title"
                android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>








</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Its look like this:

[image: example image]

Comment: Use ConstraintLayout inside your `tablerow` then use your `cardview`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Use the below code to get whatever you require:

```
<TableRow>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardview_id1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        cardview:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        cardview:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cardview_id2"
        cardview:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        cardview:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        cardview:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/finger"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_fingerprint"
            android:onClick="Move_fingerprint"
            android:src="@drawable/fingerprint_64" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/book_title_id1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="Move_fingerprint"
            android:text="Book Title"
            android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardview_id2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        cardview:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        cardview:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cardview_id3"
        cardview:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        cardview:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardview_id1"
        cardview:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/finger2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_fingerprint"
            android:onClick="Move_fingerprint"
            android:src="@drawable/fingerprint_64" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/book_title_id2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="Move_fingerprint"
            android:text="Book Title"
            android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardview_id3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        cardview:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        cardview:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        cardview:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        cardview:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardview_id2"
        cardview:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/finger3"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_fingerprint"
            android:onClick="Move_fingerprint"
            android:src="@drawable/fingerprint_64" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/book_title_id3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="Move_fingerprint"
            android:text="Book Title"
            android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</TableRow>
```

This is how it will look.

Try this, Let me know if it works.

[image]

Comment: I did it in my system and pasted here. @matan

Comment: Check my updated answer. @matan this is how it looks in my laptop.

Comment: No work, When i try to run the app i got error message @Umang Burman

Comment: This is the error: http://prntscr.com/kx08np maybe i need to use weightsum? @Umang Burman

Comment: WeightSum will be required when using LinearLayout @matan which version of ConstraintLayout is declared in your dependencies? Also, delete this line: `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Comment: Maybe we can tell in chat ? You mean to this:implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

Comment: Buramn You can open chat with me? I can to this because my rep is low

Comment: @matan do you know how to open a chat room. I've never tried

Comment: I cant open a chat room, maybe you have a skype or email ?

Comment: I'm currently not able to start a chat room with you as there is no option shown. Anyway, did you try removing this line: `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Comment: Yes i try. Maybe you have a skype or email ?